# How do I implement Queryable and Insertable for custom field types in Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have an SQL table that I want to work with through Diesel:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    record_type SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    value DECIMAL(10, 10) NOT NULL
)
```

This table generates the following schema:

```
table! {
    records (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        record_type -> Int2,
        value -> Numeric,
    }
}
```

Diesel exports decimals as `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`, but I'd like to work with `decimal::d128` instead. I also want to map `record_type` to an enum, so I declare my model like this:

```
use decimal::d128;

pub enum RecordType {
    A,
    B,
}

pub struct Record {
    pub id: i64,
    pub record_type: RecordType,
    pub value: d128,
}
```

I can't use `#derive(Queryable, Insertable)` because of non-standard type mapping, so I try to implement these traits myself:

```
impl Queryable<records::SqlType, Pg> for Record {
    type Row = (i64, i16, BigDecimal);

    fn build(row: Self::Row) -> Self {
        Record {
            id: row.0,
            record_type: match row.1 {
                1 => RecordType::A,
                2 => RecordType::B,
                _ => panic!("Wrong record type"),
            },
            value: d128!(format!("{}", row.2)),
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to implement `Insertable`. What is the `Values` associated type? Diesel's documentation is not very clear on this.

Maybe there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
bigdecimal = "0.0.10"
decimal = "2.0.4"
diesel = { version = "1.1.1", features = ["postgres", "bigdecimal", "num-bigint", "num-integer", "num-traits"] }
dotenv = "0.9.0"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I find it more convenient to create newtype wrappers that implement `ToSql` and `FromSql`. You can then build with these basic blocks to create larger types that can derive `Queryable` / `Insertable`.

This example only shows how to perform the mapping of the enum to and from a `SmallInt`, but the case for the decimal would be the same. The only difference would be in how you perform the transformations:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

mod types {
    use diesel::sql_types::*;
    use diesel::backend::Backend;
    use diesel::deserialize::{self, FromSql};
    use diesel::serialize::{self, ToSql, Output};
    use std::io;

    table! {
        records (id) {
            id -> BigInt,
            record_type -> SmallInt,
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, AsExpression, FromSqlRow)]
    #[sql_type = "SmallInt"]
    pub enum RecordType {
        A,
        B,
    }

    impl<DB: Backend> ToSql<SmallInt, DB> for RecordType
    where
        i16: ToSql<SmallInt, DB>,
    {
        fn to_sql<W>(&self, out: &mut Output<W, DB>) -> serialize::Result
        where
            W: io::Write,
        {
            let v = match *self {
                RecordType::A => 1,
                RecordType::B => 2,
            };
            v.to_sql(out)
        }
    }

    impl<DB: Backend> FromSql<SmallInt, DB> for RecordType
    where
        i16: FromSql<SmallInt, DB>,
    {
        fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&DB::RawValue>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
            let v = i16::from_sql(bytes)?;
            Ok(match v {
                1 => RecordType::A,
                2 => RecordType::B,
                _ => return Err("replace me with a real error".into()),
            })
        }
    }

    #[derive(Insertable, Queryable, Debug)]
    #[table_name = "records"]
    pub struct Record {
        pub id: i64,
        pub record_type: RecordType,
    }
}
```

There's a [draft guide describing all the derives and their annotations](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/v1.3.1/guide_drafts/trait_derives.md), but it doesn't yet mention `#[sql_type]` for an entire type. This lets Diesel know what kind of underlying storage is needed inside of the database.

See also [the Diesel tests for custom types](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/v1.3.1/diesel_tests/tests/custom_types.rs).

Comment: Yeah, this would be ideal, but unfortunately, decimal::d128 has ~30 methods and implements >50 traits, so it would be a real nuisance to reimplement those for the wrapper struct.

Comment: @hweom you could add a `Deref` implementation, so you don't have to implement those.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes, the easiest way to understand what a macro does (derives are just a different form of macros) is to ask the compiler for the expanded code. With a nightly compiler, you can do this using this command:

```
cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty expanded > expanded.rs
```

This will output the expanded code in `expanded.rs`.

We can now look at this file to see what `#[derive(Insertable)]` expands to. Naturally, I first changed the definition of `Record` to match the types that Diesel. After some cleaning up, this is the generated code:

```
impl<'insert> diesel::insertable::Insertable<records::table> for &'insert Record {
    type Values = <(
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::id, &'insert i64>>,
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::record_type, &'insert i16>>,
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::value, &'insert BigDecimal>>
    ) as diesel::insertable::Insertable<records::table>>::Values;

    #[allow(non_shorthand_field_patterns)]
    fn values(self) -> Self::Values {
        let Record {
            id: ref id,
            record_type: ref record_type,
            value: ref value,
        } = *self;
        diesel::insertable::Insertable::values((
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::id, id)),
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::record_type, record_type)),
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::value, value))))
    }
}

impl diesel::query_builder::UndecoratedInsertRecord<records::table> for Record {
}
```

We can now adapt the `Insertable` implementation for our custom types. Notice that I've changed the `Values` associated type to return values directly rather than references to the values, because for two of them, the value is created in the `values` method, so we couldn't return a reference, and for the other one, returning a reference doesn't gain much in terms of performance.

```
impl<'insert> diesel::insertable::Insertable<records::table> for &'insert Record {
    type Values = <(
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::id, i64>>,
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::record_type, i16>>,
        Option<diesel::dsl::Eq<records::value, BigDecimal>>
    ) as diesel::insertable::Insertable<records::table>>::Values;

    #[allow(non_shorthand_field_patterns)]
    fn values(self) -> Self::Values {
        let Record {
            id: ref id,
            record_type: ref record_type,
            value: ref value,
        } = *self;
        let record_type = match *record_type {
            RecordType::A => 1,
            RecordType::B => 2,
        };
        let value: BigDecimal = value.to_string().parse().unwrap();
        diesel::insertable::Insertable::values((
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::id, *id)),
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::record_type, record_type)),
            Some(::ExpressionMethods::eq(records::value, value))))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation and also for the tip on how to view the expanded code. Still going to accept Shepmaster's answer, as I don't want to explicitly use Diesel internals, which look scary enough.