# implement Diesel's Insertable

Tags: rust, insert, rust-diesel

I'm building a (gasp) blog backed by Rust's [Diesel](https://diesel.rs/) ORM.  I would like the URL of a post to include the "slug" of its title.  So, posts should be queryable by slug.  Therefore I wish to generate the slug from the title using the [slugify](https://docs.rs/slugify/0.1.0/slugify/) crate, and then store the slug in a corresponding column of the posts table in the database.

Because posts will also have a numerical ID to be generated by the DB, I wish to parse incoming posts into another struct, `NewPost`.  Then `NewPost` should implement Diesel's [Insertable](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/prelude/trait.Insertable.html), so that to record a new post in the DB it would suffice to call the resulting `insert_into` method.  However, it does not work simply to derive `Insertable`, because the value for the slug attribute needs to be generated first.

One option would be to introduce an intermediate struct, `SluggedNewPost`, and implement for it the `From<NewPost>` and `Insertable` traits:

```
struct NewPost<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    content: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Insertable)]
#[table_name="posts"]
struct SluggedNewPost<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    content: &'a str,
    slug: String,
}

impl <'a> From<NewPost<'a>> for SluggedNewPost<'a> {
    fn from(newpost: NewPost<'a> ) -> Self {
        SluggedNewPost {title: &'a newpost.title,
                        content: newpost.content,
                        slug: slugify(newpost.title)}
    }
}
```

This works for my limited purposes.  But it seems more elegant to implement the `Insertable` method on `NewPost` directly.  I tried to follow the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096462/3536879), but failed because I do not understand the code generated by the macro expansion (e.g., what is the result of dereferencing the `id` entry in the `values` tuple?).

Is it the wrong approach altogether to try to implement `Insertable` manually?  Or in doing this am I missing something very easy?  It seems like this sort of thing should be feasible pretty economically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probably best approach here is not to have a distinct `SluggedNewPost`. Diesels `#[derive(Insertable)]` is designed to be used for cases where you already have an existing struct, so that you can just put the `derive` there and things work. For cases where some additional calculation, like creating a password hash or calculating your slug the more direct tuple based insert variant is preferred. You even can mix both variants, which seems to be a good idea in this case. So your resulting code could look somehow like

```rust
#[derive(Insertable)]
#[table_name = "posts"]
struct NewPost<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    content: &'a str,
}

fn insert_with_slug(new_post: NewPost, conn: &PgConnection) -> QueryResult<()> {
    diesel::insert_into(posts::table)
        .values((new_post, posts::slug.eq(slugify(new_post.title))
        .execute(conn)?;
    Ok(())
}
```